# Excel VBA line breaks in cells slow down the execution of a merging task

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I must sort a table (A:W) where some cells are merged for each row: (P:Q) and (R:T). The code to perform that task works somehow, but every time I execute it Excel freezes and it takes around one minute for the task to be done.

I tested and the slow down definitely happens when .Merge Across:=True is executed. I have 2 line breaks in the merged cells and it seems that formatting is the cause behind. I have no clue how to fix and also I must stick to that format. If someone could help, it would be appreciated.

```
Sub Data_Sort()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range

Set rng1 = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:W2", Range("A2:W2").End(xlDown)) 'whole table except the headers
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Data").Range("P2:Q2", Range("P2:Q2").End(xlDown)) 'columns P&Q with merged cells on each row
Set rng3 = Worksheets("Data").Range("R2:T2", Range("R2:T2").End(xlDown)) 'columns R,S,T with merged cells on each row

'===============
'UNMERGE CELLS
'===============

rng1.MergeCells = False 'unmerge all merged cells in the sheet

'===============
'SORT DATA
'===============

With Worksheets("Data").Sort.SortFields 'set up the criteria to sort data alphabetically starting with column A and ending with column G
    .Clear
    .Add Key:=Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)), Order:=xlAscending
    .Add Key:=Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)), Order:=xlAscending
    .Add Key:=Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown)), Order:=xlAscending
    .Add Key:=Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown)), Order:=xlAscending
    .Add Key:=Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown)), Order:=xlAscending
    .Add Key:=Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown)), Order:=xlAscending
    .Add Key:=Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown)), Order:=xlAscending
End With

With Worksheets("Data").Sort 'sort data following to the setups above
    .SetRange rng1
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .Apply
End With

'===============
'MERGE & FORMAT
'===============

With rng2 'merge and format each row in the range P:Q
    .Merge Across:=True
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .AddIndent = True
    .IndentLevel = 1
End With

With rng3 'merge and format each row in the range R:T
    .Merge Across:=True
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .AddIndent = True
    .IndentLevel = 1
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint (using F9) when calling ```With rng2```, then run step-by-step (using F8) to identify which line actually causes the freeze ? How many rows of data do you have ?

Comment: Thank you for asking. From what I tested before, and just a moment again using a breakpoint, the exact part where the code execution slows down is `.Merge Across:=True`. After more tests it is now obvious Excel is not happy with the original formatting in the merged cells. I have 2 line breaks in each cells and it is what is slowing down the execution when merging again. But I need to keep that format, so if you have any idea how to speed the code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not come from `Merge` but rather from the way you declare `rng1`, `rng2` and `rng3`. Using `.End(xlDown)` means your range will go from your starting row to the *last row of the sheet*, rather than to the *last row of your datatable*. As a proof, here is the number of rows for each Range:

```
MsgBox ("Rng1 rows : " & rng1.Rows.Count & vbNewLine & _
        "Rng2 rows : " & rng2.Rows.Count & vbNewLine & _
        "Rng3 rows : " & rng3.Rows.Count)
```

[image]

Multiply that by the number of columns of each `Range`, it is understandable that allocation/desallocation of memory and merging/unmerging cells for such massive `Range`s takes some time.

Please try this new code (feel free to remove `MsgBox` once tests are done):

```
Sub Data_Sort()

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
        Set rng1 = .Range("A2", "W" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row) 'whole table except the headers
        Set rng2 = .Range("P2", "Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row) 'columns P&Q with merged cells on each row
        Set rng3 = .Range("R2", "T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row) 'columns R,S,T with merged cells on each row
    

        MsgBox ("Rng1 rows : " & rng1.Rows.Count & vbNewLine & _
                "Rng2 rows : " & rng2.Rows.Count & vbNewLine & _
                "Rng3 rows : " & rng3.Rows.Count)
                
        '===============
        'UNMERGE CELLS
        '===============

        rng1.MergeCells = False                  'unmerge all merged cells in the sheet

        '===============
        'SORT DATA
        '===============

        With .Sort.SortFields                    'set up the criteria to sort data alphabetically starting with column A and ending with column G
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Range("A2", "A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row), Order:=xlAscending
            .Add Key:=Range("B2", "B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row), Order:=xlAscending
            .Add Key:=Range("C2", "C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row), Order:=xlAscending
            .Add Key:=Range("D2", "D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row), Order:=xlAscending
            .Add Key:=Range("E2", "E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row), Order:=xlAscending
            .Add Key:=Range("F2", "F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row), Order:=xlAscending
            .Add Key:=Range("G2", "G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row), Order:=xlAscending
        End With

        With .Sort                               'sort data following to the setups above
            .SetRange rng1
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With

        '===============
        'MERGE & FORMAT
        '===============

        With rng2                                'merge and format each row in the range P:Q
            .Merge Across:=True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .AddIndent = True
            .IndentLevel = 1
        End With

        With rng3                                'merge and format each row in the range R:T
            .Merge Across:=True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .AddIndent = True
            .IndentLevel = 1
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

If you have a squared data table (each column ends on the same row) **and nothing written below the table**, a better approch would be to hold the last row in a variable `lLastRow` and call it everytime you need it:

```
Sub Data_Sort_With_UsedRange()

    Dim rng1        As Range
    Dim rng2        As Range
    Dim rng3        As Range
    Dim lLastRow    As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
        lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
        
        Set rng1 = .Range("A2", "W" & lLastRow)  'whole table except the headers
        Set rng2 = .Range("P2", "Q" & lLastRow)  'columns P&Q with merged cells on each row
        Set rng3 = .Range("R2", "T" & lLastRow)  'columns R,S,T with merged cells on each row
    

        MsgBox ("Rng1 rows : " & rng1.Rows.Count & vbNewLine & _
                "Rng2 rows : " & rng2.Rows.Count & vbNewLine & _
                "Rng3 rows : " & rng3.Rows.Count)
                
        '===============
        'UNMERGE CELLS
        '===============

        rng1.MergeCells = False                  'unmerge all merged cells in the sheet

        '===============
        'SORT DATA
        '===============

        With .Sort.SortFields                    'set up the criteria to sort data alphabetically starting with column A and ending with column G
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Range("A2", "A" & lLastRow), Order:=xlAscending
            .Add Key:=Range("B2", "B" & lLastRow), Order:=xlAscending
            .Add Key:=Range("C2", "C" & lLastRow), Order:=xlAscending
            .Add Key:=Range("D2", "D" & lLastRow), Order:=xlAscending
            .Add Key:=Range("E2", "E" & lLastRow), Order:=xlAscending
            .Add Key:=Range("F2", "F" & lLastRow), Order:=xlAscending
            .Add Key:=Range("G2", "G" & lLastRow), Order:=xlAscending
        End With

        With .Sort                               'sort data following to the setups above
            .SetRange rng1
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With

        '===============
        'MERGE & FORMAT
        '===============

        With rng2                                'merge and format each row in the range P:Q
            .Merge Across:=True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .AddIndent = True
            .IndentLevel = 1
        End With

        With rng3                                'merge and format each row in the range R:T
            .Merge Across:=True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .AddIndent = True
            .IndentLevel = 1
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT :**

It seems range declaration was only a part of the problem. The rest of the lag was due to visual and calculation updates of the worksheet. For context, look at this [Guide to efficient VBA code](https://masterofficevba.com/vba-coding-constructs/efficient-excel-vba-code-best-practices/).

To fix it, try adding this code before calling `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")`:

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .StatusBar = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .PrintCommunication = False
End With
```

And this one after `End With`:

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .StatusBar = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .PrintCommunication = True
End With
```

You can look at execution duration with the [Timer function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function), using `startTimer` before the code and `endTimer` after. Total duration is displayed with `MsgBox "Duration = " & endTimer - startTimer & "s"`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed it is more efficient to not go through the whole sheet. I applied the code for a square table and it works. I will use your code from now on. Still in the meantime, I found that the format of the merged cells is the main reason of the slowdown. I have line breaks in these cells and from what I see it takes time for Excel to execute the merge command because of these. I tested with your fix and unfortunately the issue remains.

Comment: Merging cells in Excel is a well-known non-efficient process. Maybe try to loop though the rows of ```rng2``` and ```rng3``` and use ```.MergeCells = True``` instead of ```Merge Across:=True```. I'm note sure about the result but it's worth testing. Another option would be to use ```.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenterAcrossSelection```, which only merge cells *visually* and is faster than the ```Merge``` property, but you would loose the left alignment.

Comment: @D.Fox I did some tests and I think your lag is due to visual updates of your Excel sheet. Test for 500 rows of random data: around 30s with updates enabled, around 0,08s with updates disabled. See the edit on my answer.

Comment: @ Vincent It works like a charm with your edit, thanks a lot. Only takes 2 seconds to execute the whole code. I would have never think to deal with the issue that way. Besides the timer function is a nice tip, I will reuse it. And last thanks for the guide to efficient coding I'm starting to study it.

Comment: @D.Fox You're very welcome ! :) This guide helped me a lot to speed up my code, I hope it will be as helpful to you.

Comment: If you're not already using it, consider adding https://rubberduckvba.com/ to your VBA Editor. It offers many useful features, such as *code inspection*, *unit testing* and *auto-indent*.